# missing WAL file on standby server following a backup

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2

I seem to have an intermittent problem with my postgres backup/restore to standby

Postgres, is version 9.2 running on red hat 6 enterprise

i have a production server (PROD1) and a hot standby (STANDBY1), on sunday evening i have a script which puts 
PROD1 into backup mode, performs a tar on the $PGDATA directory, copies the file to STANDBY1, a script on STANDBY1 
is then called to stop postgres on STANDBY1, unpack the tar, and start postgres again.

In the meantime the archive_command on PROD1 is continuing to copy WAL files over the STANDBY1, so in theory STANDBY1
will be brought up to date. Then for the remainder of the week the WAL files are applied until the next Sunday when the
process starts again.

code extract for backup script on PROD1

```
psql -X -U postgres --set ON_ERROR_STOP=on <<PSQL
select pg_start_backup('${WEEK_START}_DataBackup','true');
PSQL

tar -zcf $WEEKLYBACKUP_DIRECTORY/full_backup_${WEEK_START}.tar.gz --exclude=$PGDATA/pg_xlog/* --exclude=$PGDATA/pg_xlogArchive/* 
--exclude=$PGDATA/pg_xlogRestored --exclude=$PGADTA/postmaster.pid --exclude=$PGDATA/postmaster.opts $PGDATA/

psql -X -U postgres --set ON_ERROR_STOP=on <<PSQL
select pg_stop_backup();
PSQL

scp -p $WEEKLYBACKUP_DIRECTORY/full_backup_${WEEK_START}.tar.gz $DR_SERVER:$WEEKLYBACKUP_DIRECTORY/.

ssh -T $DR_SERVER <<EOF >> $MAILFILE
  cd /var/lib/pgsql/Scripts
  ./postgres-hotStandby $WEEK_START Y
EOF
```

code extract for hotstandby script on STANDBY1

```
pg_ctl stop -D $PGDATA -m i >> $LOGFILE
tar -zxf $WEEKLYBACKUP_DIRECTORY/full_backup_${RESTORE_WEEK}.tar.gz

# create a recovery file
echo "standby_mode = 'on'" >$PGDATA/recovery.conf
echo "primary_conninfo = 'host=${LIVE_SERVER}'" >>$PGDATA/recovery.conf
echo "restore_command = 'cp -f $PGDATA/pg_xlog/%f $PGDATA/pg_xlogRestored'" >>$PGDATA/recovery.conf
echo "trigger_file = '${PGDATA}/failover'" >>$PGDATA/recovery.conf
sed -i 's/#hot_standby = off/hot_standby = on/g' $PGDATA/postgresql.conf
pg_ctl -w -D $PGDATA start
```

the above process works every second time it runs and fails the other times, giving the message

> "psql: FATAL:  the database system is starting up"

when i try and 
get into psql.

looking in the log file on STANDBY1, postgres is awaiting a WAL file which it says...

> cp: cannot stat
>   `/vol2/postgres92/pgsql/data/pg_xlog/000000010000005200000003': No
>   such file or directory   2015-04-24 00:10:40 EDT -LOG:  streaming
>   replication successfully connected to primary   2015-04-24 00:10:40
>   EDT -FATAL:  could not receive data from WAL stream: FATAL:  requested
>   WAL segment 000000010000005200000003 has already been removed

when `pg_start_backup` is run, this creates a WAL file which is shipped to STANDBY1 (eg. 000000010000005200000003), and when `pg_stop_backup` is run this 
creates a end of backup WAL (eg. 000000010000005200000003.00000020.backup), which is also correctly shipped to STANDBY1. But when the failure occurs 
the pg_start_backup WAL seems to go missing on the STANDBY1 server.

hopefully this all makes some sort of sense to someone, any ideas what is going wrong? I seem unable to reproduce this on my test systems, and i'm thinking it 
may be a timing issue as due to the size and location of PROD1 and STANDBY1, the scp between the servers takes 15mins.

thanks for any help you can give

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part generating `recovery.conf` is suspicious:

```
echo "restore_command = 'cp -f $PGDATA/pg_xlog/%f $PGDATA/pg_xlogRestored'" >>$PGDATA/recovery.conf
```

It seems that the source and destination of this `restore_command` are reversed.

Compare yours to the example from the doc in [Continuous archiving](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/continuous-archiving.html):

```
restore_command = 'cp /mnt/server/archivedir/%f %p'
```

The restore must copy from the archive directory (which typically is outside `$PGDATA` and entirely under the DBA's control) into `$PGDATA/pg_xlog` (as expanded by `%p`).

I'm assuming that `$PGDATA/pg_xlogRestored` is your archive directory since I don't see what else it could be. Personally I'd place it outside of `$PGDATA` by principle but that's not mandatory.

Comment: this looks to be my misunderstanding of how this works. Do i even need the restore_command if the live server is log shipping to the $PGDATA/pg_xlog folder on the standby server?

so i currently have the archive_command on the live server whick is copying directly to the $PGDATA/pg_xlog folder on standby. So in my understanding the WAL files are where they need to be on standby. Is this not the case?

Comment: Yes, the `restore_command` is needed and the live server **must not** copy directly into `$PGDATA/pg_xlog` on the standby. It must copy into the archive directory. Only `restore_command` is allowed to copy into `pg_xlog` and only on demand (when postgres calls it).

Comment: ok thanks, i'll will do some rejigging of the commands and scripts and see how it goes

Comment: Hi, i've rolled this chance out to live now and it's fixed the problem. Thanks for your help Daniel.